# C++ - New SFML project with the same settings

Tags: c++, copy, dependencies, settings, sfml

I set up a new project and configured it to use SFML as instructed here:
http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-vc.php

I'm going to be developing a chess game, but before that, I will probably create several projects to experiment with SFML and I wondered whether it's possible to copy the solution settings (like the dependencies) to a new project instead of manually configuring SFML every time I create a new project/solution. Is it possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so?

I've already tried going to File -> New -> Project From Existing Code but that apparently didn't work as the dependencies weren't there in the new project.

I'd appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Create your base project with all the settings
2- File (in upper left)
3- Export Template
4- Follow the instructions
5- When you make your project, select "template" instead of the other options
6- Tada!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but "Export Template" doesn't seem to be in the file menu: http://i40.tinypic.com/29xizgj.png I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express, if that makes a difference

Comment: I believe Visual Studio 2010 does not support creation of templates with export template for C++ (Only C# and VB). You could upgrade your visual studios edition to either Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 and they will support this feature or you can create the project template manually http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185291(v=vs.100).aspx . Upgrading will be the easiest option.

Comment: I got Visual Studio 2013 and BWG's method worked :) One more question though: Can Visual C++ 2010 open and use projects from VS 2013 properly or are there issues with it? My school only has Visual C++ 2010, which is my reason for asking.

Comment: I doubt it. I just tried opening a VS2013 project on VS2012, and it said the build tools cannot be found. It might be as simple as doing some sort of port to the older system, but I don't know.